# How to use global object in Class

Tags: php, mysql, oop, php-mysqlidb

I am wondering how to get the following to be a global function. I want the class function to not have to keep logging into the MySQL I am using

https://github.com/joshcam/PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class#initialization

This is what I have done so far, would that work?

```
<?php
require_once('system/MysqliDb.php');
$db = new MysqliDb ('host', 'username', 'password', 'databaseName');

class system{
  public function __construct() {
    $db;
 }

}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass in the database object using "dependency injection"

```
class system {
  protected $_db;
  public function __construct(MysqliDb $db){
    $this->_db = $db;
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry but that did not work the error I get is follows [Fri Jun 05 14:32:47 2015] [error] [client 49.199.36.167] PHP Catchable fatal error:  Argument 1 passed to system::__construct() must be an instance of MysqliDb, none given, called in /home/my$

Comment: That means you didn't pass it anything.  Do you call it as new system($db) ... ?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use getInstance() method.

```
class system {
  protected $_db;
  public function __construct() {
    $this->_db = MysqliDb::getInstance();
  }
}
```